# How to add the Github actions markdown omitting the repository url

Tags: github, markdown, github-actions

The snippet to add the repository build status markdown is:

```
![](https://github.com/${owner}/${repo}/workflows/${name}/badge.svg)
```

But, I don't want to keep the `owner` static, since the repository can be forked. Is there someway in markdown to get the `https://github.com/${owner}` from a variable?

Comment: Why not just let the people who fork it change the name themselves. Note that when a repo is forked, the new fork can have a different name, so you also have to worry about that. Not only that, but the workflow can also have a different name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there someway in markdown to get the https://github.com/${owner} from a variable?

Not directly with [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown)](https://github.github.com/gfm/) alone, which is entirely static.

You would need to use a static website generator (like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) or [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/)) in order to replace that variable by a value.
That would not be dynamic though.